# LLVM IR cannot break out of the loop

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am new to LLVM, I am compiling the scripting language I wrote into LLVM IR and running it with jit

This is my script code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  if (i == 5) {
    print(100);
    break;
  }
  print(i);
}
```

This is the compiled LLVM IR:

```
; ModuleID = 'jit'
source_filename = "jit"

declare i32 @print(i32)

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %i = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %i, align 4
  br label %loop

loop:                                             ; preds = %loopStep, %entry
  %i1 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %0 = icmp slt i32 %i1, 10
  br i1 %0, label %loopBody, label %loopEnd

loopBody:                                         ; preds = %loop
  %i2 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %1 = icmp eq i32 %i2, 5
  br i1 %1, label %then, label %else

loopStep:                                         ; preds = %merge
  %i4 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %2 = add i32 %i4, 1
  store i32 %2, i32* %i, align 4
  br label %loop

loopEnd:                                          ; preds = %then, %loop
  ret i32 0

merge:                                            ; preds = %else, %then
  %i3 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %3 = call i32 @print(i32 %i3)
  br label %loopStep

then:                                             ; preds = %loopBody
  %4 = call i32 @print(i32 100)
  br label %loopEnd
  br label %merge

else:                                             ; preds = %loopBody
  br label %merge
}
```

This is the result of running jit:

```
0
1
2
3
4
100
5
6
7
8
9
```

I think the correct route when `1==5` is `%then -> %loopEnd -> ret`, but the result of jit running is completely unexpected

I don't know what went wrong, thanks for the help

Comment: You have two `br` instructions in one basic block there, which isn't legal and will cause something to break. Look for whatever creates that `br` pair. (And whatever you do, whatenever the problem, call verifyFunction() to see what it has to say.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think LLVM IR is as flexible as assembly, but it is not the case. When generating LLVM IR, a lot of processing needs to be done. For example, there cannot be multiple consecutive `br`s and multiple consecutive `ret`s.